# Availability of PHP 7.2.21?

Tags: php

Does anyone know when PHP 7.2.21 will be available - looking for fixes for CVE-2019-11041 and CVE-2019-11042.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PHP 7.2.21 Released](https://www.php.net/archive/2019.php#2019-08-01-3)

> #### PHP 7.2.21 Release Announcement
>
> The PHP development team announces the immediate availability of PHP
> 7.2.21. This is a security release which also contains several minor bug fixes.
>
> All PHP 7.2 users are encouraged to upgrade to this version.
>
> For source downloads of PHP 7.2.21 please visit our [downloads
> page](http://www.php.net/downloads.php).

[How do I install a .tar.gz (or .tar.bz2) file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/)